# .Net SQL Server connection simple class with procedure

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need write simple class in C#. I have 2 tables. But for understanding I use just 1 table.

```
public string[] GetCustOrders(int CustomerCODE)
{
    SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection("server=(local);Initial Catalog=dbName;Integrated Security=True");

    SqlDataAdapter myData = new SqlDataAdapter("CustOrdersOrdersDetails", myConn);
    myData.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    myData.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CustomerCODE", SqlDbType.Int, 0));
    myData.SelectCommand.Parameters["@CustomerCODE"].Value = CustomerCODE;

    //  string[] as = string[6];
    string[] as1 = string[3];
    //       string[] as2 = string[3];

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    myData.Fill(ds);

    return as;
}
```

And my stored procedure code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CustOrdersOrdersDetails 
    @CustomerCODE int
AS
    SELECT 
        Name, 
        Action,
        Comments
    FROM 
        System2
    WHERE 
        Code = @CustomerCODE
```

The stored procedure will select just 1 row from the table. But I don`t know how from`SqlDataAdapter` get each value of cell of this one row and give this value for my array as1.

Ex., "as[1]=" and after = I need give value of Action from selected row.

I know this simple, but I think... and think, that I can do this just give all values of my row to the DataSet and after that give each value of each cell to each string from my array. But I tray and cant finish this class...

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int i = 0;    
// For each table in the DataSet, print the row values.
foreach(DataTable table in ds.Tables)
{
    foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
        {
            as[i]=row[column]);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```